# C# - Get console cursor position on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, console, command-line-interface, cursor

I'm trying to get the terminal's cursor's position with `C#`.
I did it on Windows many times. I did it thus:

```cs
public Pointer get() {
  Point pos = new Point();
  GetCursorPos(ref pos);
  return pos;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Point lpPoint);
```

Of course this doesn't work on Linux, I'm importing Windows dlls.
How can I do this in linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Console.SetCursorPosition

An example would be like this:

```
Console.Clear(); //this clears the console
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, Console.CursorTop); //this sets back to beginning
```

You can get the current position with this:

```
var CurrentCursorPositionConsole = Console.GetCursorPosition();
```

Comment: "console cursor position" in OPs message. He doesn't state the mouse anywhere.

Comment: OP says in post he can't return the console cursor. If they want the mouse they should clarify a bit more, but this answer fits the current OP post Not to mention who uses a mouse cursor in Linux lol

Comment: Well, in the example they provided for Windows, they were getting the coordinates for the mouse cursor, so...

Comment: Yeah, but he said he is on linux. So his current example is wrong regardless.